# In .Net, copy one jagged array to another that is not linked

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

I am having a nightmare of a time with this.  What is the fastest method in .Net 4.5 to copy a jagged array to another jagged array that is completely separate.  Nothing links the two together.  If I change one, the other doesn't change.

```
Dim Array1()() As Integer = New Integer(80)() {}
For i = 0 To 80
  Array1(i) = New Integer() {}
Next
Array(22) = {123,456}
Array(33) = {222,333,444}
```

I want to copy Array1()() to array Array2()() and have it be total independent of Array1.  Any changes I make in Array2 are not reflected in Array1.

I need the fastest method possible because this is in a massive For Loop that is getting call a lot and it is the slowest aspect of my function.

In addition, if I should be storing my Array in a different data type that would be faster for this type of operation, please let me know.

Thanks for any help you can provide,
AD

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670720/extremely-fast-way-to-clone-the-values-of-a-jagged-array-into-a-second-array

Comment: Wow, I have been searching here for the last 3 hours and never hit that question/answer.  It works.  Thanks.