# Why does sub-arrays of a jagged array become sorted when I sort the sub-arrays of a copy of it?

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, jagged-arrays

I had the following jagged array-

```cs
int[][] triangle = 
{
    new int[] {    3    },
    new int[] {   7,4   },
    new int[] {  2,4,6  },
    new int[] { 8,5,9,3 }
};
```

Then I made a copy of it-

```cs
int[][] temporaryTriangle = new int[triangle.Length][];
Array.Copy(triangle, temporaryTriangle, triangle.Length);
```

and I sorted the sub-arrays of the copy-

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < temporaryTriangle.Length; i++)
{
    Array.Sort(temporaryTriangle[i]);
}
```

and I found out that the sub-arrays of the source array has been sorted too!
My question is why this has happened, I mean why sub-arrays of the array become sorted when I sort  the sub-arrays of the copy?

Usage:

```cs
foreach (var subarray in triangle)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", subarray));

foreach (var subarray in temporaryTriangle)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", subarray));

// Output:
// 3
// 4 7
// 2 4 6
// 3 5 8 9
// 3
// 4 7
// 2 4 6
// 3 5 8 9
```

I asked what's the problem not how to solve it. So [Extremely fast way to clone the values of a jagged array into a second array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670720/extremely-fast-way-to-clone-the-values-of-a-jagged-array-into-a-second-array) does not answer my question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extremely fast way to clone the values of a jagged array into a second array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4670720/extremely-fast-way-to-clone-the-values-of-a-jagged-array-into-a-second-array)

Comment: @OlivierRogier My question is why this happens, not how to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Though you think you made a copy of that array(which in fact you did), you only deep copied the outer array, and each element was copied by a reference. You should loop the new array, and deep copy each element of the previous one into it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that you aren't copying the child array elements, you copy just the reference of every array inside `triangle`. You can confirm it using this code

```cs
for (int i = 0; i < triangle.Length; i++)
{
    var result = ReferenceEquals(triangle[i], temporaryTriangle[i]);
}
```

It returns `true` for every iteration. So, in your case you should copy every element manually

Answer (score 2):

The `Array.Copy` only copies the first level of cells' array, that are an array of references to childs arrays... So only these references are duplicated.

Hence the link provided as a duplicate question solve the problem by doing the deep copy of each child leaf.

You need to clone each sub-array and so-on: if you have a `[][][]...` jagged array you need to manage each level of the tree, branch by branch, to duplicate each level with `Array.Copy` up to leaf with another `Array.Copy`.

Therefore if you copy only the first level, and then if you modify a leaf using `temporaryTriangle`, reading `triangle` results in getting values from the same cells.

In fact only the reference value (memory address) of `temporaryTriangle` and `triangle` are distinct: all other references and content is shared between these variables.

Answer (score 0):

[ *pointerToArray, *pointerToArray2, *pointerToArray3 ]

When you copy, you only copy the reference / pointers, not the actual arrays themselves.

You have to copy the inner array as well.